# set foreign key in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have these two tables in my android app: 'account' and 'person'  .

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table account "
            + "(accountId integer primary key autoincrement,bank_name text,hesab_num text unique,cart_num text unique,cvv2 text,expire_date date , pId integer)");
    db.execSQL("create table person (personId integer primary key autoincrement,name text)");

}
```

.

```
account:
    ACCOUNT_COLUMN_BANK
    ACCOUNT_COLUMN_HESAB
    ACCOUNT_COLUMN_CART
    ACCOUNT_COLUMN_CVV2
    ACCOUNT_COLUMN_EXPIRE_DATE
    ACCOUNT_COLUMN_P_ID     // foreign key for person


person:
    PERSON_COLUMN_NAME
```

and i have this method in android dbHelper class:

```
public boolean insertAccount(Person person, Bank bank) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues bankValues = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues personValues = new ContentValues();

    personValues.put(PERSON_COLUMN_NAME, person.getName());
    long id = db.insert(PERSON_TABLE_NAME, null, personValues);  // get id of person

    bankValues.put(ACCOUNT_COLUMN_BANK, bank.getBankName());
    bankValues.put(ACCOUNT_COLUMN_HESAB, bank.getAccountNumber());
    bankValues.put(ACCOUNT_COLUMN_CART, bank.getCardNumber());
    bankValues.put(ACCOUNT_COLUMN_CVV2, bank.getCvv2());
    bankValues.put(ACCOUNT_COLUMN_EXPIRE_DATE, bank.getExpireDate()
            .toString());
    bankValues.put(ACCOUNT_COLUMN_P_ID, (int) id);   // set id of person in account table
    db.insert(ACCOUNT_TABLE_NAME, null, bankValues);

    return true;
}
```

most of the times that i call this method , foreign key in account table is null. why? and what i must do ?

point: foreign key can be Repetitious , because a person can have many account.

Comment: Your `insertAccount` functions creates both an account and a person. So how can there by more accounts than persons?

Comment: @CL. : My method is incompleteness because i must check if person is Repetitious then only save account.

Comment: So your actual question is how to check for a duplicate name?

Comment: no. assume that every person can have an account. now when i call this method most of the times ,  foreign key in account table is null. I realize that when i debug it,  it work correctly , but when i run it encounter with this problem.